Issue with Filamentphp/ Minio unable to save file to bucket with FileUpload component
I have an issue with FileUpload Component with this issue :

Unable to retrieve the mime_type for file at location: livewire-tmp/3gV8mEXfLVdtzdvzKRuiGxHRe2Kjoj-metaSWNvbmUtQkxDLnBuZw%3D%3D-.png.


[previous exception] [object] (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException(code: 0): cURL error 7: Failed to connect to minio.cdm.local port 80 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://minio.cdm.local/public/livewire-tmp/3gV8mEXfLVdtzdvzKRuiGxHRe2Kjoj-metaSWNvbmUtQkxDLnBuZw%3D%3D-.png at /app/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:275)

I've already test all configs.
this is my docker-compose with Traefik :
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v3.0"
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      # - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entryPoints.web.address=:80"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - internal-network
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"

 cdm-app:
    depends_on:
      - traefik
      - mysql
      - minio
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: docker/local/images/cdm-app/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ../../src/cdm-app:/app
      - ./conf/php-fpm/docker.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/docker.conf
      -  ./conf/php-fpm/docker-fpm.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-fpm.ini
    networks:
      - internal-network

  nginx-cdm-app:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./conf/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ../../src/cdm-app:/app
    depends_on:
      - cdm-app
      - mysql
      - traefik
    networks:
      - internal-network
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx-cdm-app.rule=Host(`cdm.local`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx-cdm-app.entrypoints=web" cdm-app:
    depends_on:
      - traefik
      - mysql
      - minio
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: docker/local/images/cdm-app/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ../../src/cdm-app:/app
      - ./conf/php-fpm/docker.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/docker.conf
      -  ./conf/php-fpm/docker-fpm.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-fpm.ini
    networks:
      - internal-network

  minio:
    image: 'minio/minio:RELEASE.2024-08-03T04-33-23Z'
    depends_on:
      - traefik
    ports:
      - '9000:9000'
      - '9001:9001'
    restart: always
    environment:
        MINIO_ROOT_USER: minio
        MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: "password"
        MINIO_HTTP_TRACE: /dev/stdout
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mc", "ready", "local"]
      interval: 3s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 10
    volumes:
      - '../../data/minio:/data/minio'
    command: 'minio server /data/minio --console-address ":9001"'
    networks:
      - internal-network
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
     # Console
      - "traefik.http.routers.minio-console.rule=Host(`console.cdm.local`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.minio-console.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.minio-console.service=minio-console"
      - "traefik.http.services.minio-console.loadbalancer.server.port=9001"
      # APi
      - "traefik.http.routers.minio.rule=Host(`minio.cdm.local`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.minio.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.minio.service=minio"
      - "traefik.http.services.minio.loadbalancer.server.port=9000"

I have already set my /etc/hosts to have DNS to localhost
here my config .env for Laravel :
APP_URL=http://cdm.local

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxxxxx
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxx
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=public
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=true
AWS_ENDPOINT=http://minio.cdm.local
AWS_URL=http://minio.cdm.local/public
MINIO_ENDPOINT=http://minio.cdm.local

I tried this test code :
Route::get('/test', function () {
    $fileName = 'test_file.png';


$filePath = sys_get_temp_dir() . '/' . $fileName;
file_put_contents($filePath, 'Test file content');

if (file_exists($filePath)) {
    echo "Fichier temporaire créé avec succès.\n";
} else {
    echo "Erreur lors de la création du fichier temporaire.\n";
    return;
}

try {
    $result = Storage::disk('s3')->put('test/' . $fileName, file_get_contents($filePath));
    echo $result ? "Fichier téléchargé avec succès.\n" : "Échec du téléchargement du fichier.\n";
  
    $mimeType = Storage::disk('s3')->mimeType('test/' . $fileName);
    echo "Type MIME du fichier téléchargé: " . $mimeType . "\n";

    // Récupérez l'URL du fichier
    $url = Storage::disk('s3')->url('test/' . $fileName);
    echo "URL du fichier téléchargé: " . $url . "\n";
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo "Erreur lors du téléchargement ou de la récupération des informations du fichier: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}

});



and get this error :

Fichier temporaire créé avec succès.

Erreur lors du téléchargement ou de la récupération des informations du fichier: Unable to write file at location: test_file.png. Error executing "PutObject" on "http://minio.cdm.local/public/test_file.png"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to minio.cdm.local port 80 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://minio.cdm.local/public/test_file.png
That's weird because the file wasn't put in bucket.
Where am I missing something ?

Try change .ENV minio endpoint to your docker container:
AWS_ENDPOINT=http://minio:9000

That's weird because the file wasn't put in bucket. - you are saving file on local storage first, when you are trying to put file to your minio bucket. Why are you saving file localy first? Just store your files in minio only.
